# Java: Reading from a txt file in a folder inside the resourcefolder

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, imageicon

I am creating a program that has to read an image from a folder inside the resource folder. At the moment I have just put all of the images in the resource folder however, having many images, this is not a viable approach. I am using the:

`new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream()` method and it works for reading directly from the resource folder but, when I put the pictures inside a folder, which is in the resource folder, it is not working...

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in a small console test for me

```
-resources
  -imagefolder
    -image.png

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imagefolder/image.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the folder name, that is under the resources folder, as well in the path. Like ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(foldername/image.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(Yourclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/YourFolder/YourImage.ext");
```

it should work.